# HTML/CSS: Hanging section numbers to the left of left-aligned heading text

Tags: css, html-heading

How can I create hanging section numbers with CSS? In other words,

- heading text should be left-aligned at the same horizontal position as the text but
- section numbers section numbers should be "hanging" in the left column.

Probably the best example to illustrate this is browser's rendering of numbered lists:

---

1. Heading 1

   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
2. Heading 2

   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

---

Is there any sane way to do this in CSS with numbers before heading tags (for all levels)?

Simple example HTML to modify:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>First h1 heading</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>

<h2>First h2 heading</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any demo code we could work with?

Comment: Here you go: http://gist.github.com/161520

Answer (score 3):

I've got this done. Essentially, every counter has to be floated to the left:

```
h1:before {
    content: counter(chapter) ". ";
    float:left;
    width: 1.2cm;
}
```

and every heading has to get a margin and a `left` attribute:

```
h1 {    
    left: 1.2cm;
    margin-left: -1.2cm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
h1, h2, h3 {
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`h1 { margin-left: -10px; }` will work until your header goes to two lines.

How about this:

`h1 { text-indent: -10px }`